# delete every nth page of a pdf

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I'm pretty new to python and I am trying to delete every 3rd page from a very large pdf file (like 10,000+ pages). Currently I can just look at the pdf in thumbnail view, and drag to select every page in the third column, and then hit delete. Obviously this is a very manual way to do it, it crashes the computer often, etc... I figure I should be able to do this with code right? I've looked around and found some similar topics out there but I can't seem to modify the code to work. Right now I am using the pyPDF module. (I know there is a pyPDF2 module out there, but I think the pyPDF should be fine. If not I am happy to change.) Here is what I have so far:

```
from pyPdf import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

doc = "TEST_IN.pdf"
inputpdf = PdfFileReader(open(doc,"rb"))
output = PdfFileWriter()
n = 3

for i in xrange(inputpdf.numPages):
    if i % 3 != 0
        output.addPage(inputpdf.getpage(i))

with open ("document-page%s.pdf" % i, "wb") as outputStream:
    output.write(outputStream)
```

Right now I'm getting a syntax error on the statement: if i % 3 != 0

Can anyone help me fix the code? Thanks in advance. I appreciate everyone helping out on this site.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a single colon, `:`, after all conditional statements such as `if`, `while`, `else` and what have you. You're already doing it right in the `for` loop and the `with` statement but also need it in `if i % 3 != 0`.

```
from pyPdf import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

doc = "TEST_IN.pdf"
inputpdf = PdfFileReader(open(doc,"rb"))
output = PdfFileWriter()
n = 3

for i in xrange(inputpdf.numPages):
    if i % 3 != 0:
        output.addPage(inputpdf.getpage(i))

with open ("document-page%s.pdf" % i, "wb") as outputStream:
    output.write(outputStream)
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply forgot the colon at the end of your if statement.

Change that line to

```
if i % 3 != 0:
```